# How to rewrite a function to avoid jslint return a conditional instead of an assignment warning

Tags: javascript, jslint

My code works as intended.  How do I re-write `return cachedPromise[reqKey] = $http.get(apiUrl)`
so that jsLint stop throwing warnings.  I'd rather not block this error.

```
return cachedPromise[reqKey] = $http.get(apiUrl)
    .then(function(result){
        console.log('http then results', result.data);
        return result.data;
     }, function(data, status){
         return $q.reject('error in teh gifson' + 'data: ' +  data + 'status: ' + status);
     })
    .finally( function(){
        delete cachedPromise[reqKey];
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
cachedPromise[reqKey] = $http.get(apiUrl)...;
return cachedPromise[reqKey];
```